# Right Align MenuItems in WPF

Tags: wpf, menuitem, right-align

Can i right align the menu items in WPF?

Thanks 
Sharath

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023638/how-do-i-right-align-the-help-menu-item-in-wpf

Answer (score 4):

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">            
        <MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" Header="aaa">
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Right" Header="bbb">
        </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

Although the implementation is a little screwy.

If you want to have the menu items in the top menu go from right to left, add FlowDirection="RightToLeft" to your Menu.
If you want to have an item aligned right in a dropdown, do the following:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" >Content</TextBlock>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

If you want to do both, you actually have to set HorizontalAlignment="Left" instead of right, as the FlowDirection reverses the right and left in the Alignments.  I don't know why, but that's what you have to do.

Comment: Isn't it wonderful when you find out that one solution screws up another?  Seriously, try making a menu with the FlowDirection="RtL" and aligning things right, they all go left!

Answer (score 3):

[How do I right-align the 'help' menu item in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023638/how-do-i-right-align-the-help-menu-item-in-wpf)

I like the second answer with the grid way.