# Right aligned menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, dockpanel

Following this question: [How do I right-align the 'help' menu item in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023638/how-do-i-right-align-the-help-menu-item-in-wpf)

I've made a menu which the ItemsPanelTemplate is a DockPanel with HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

If I add at least one item right aligned, it works fine: http://puu.sh/3uFje.png

But if there is no one item on the right side, this happens: http://puu.sh/3uFmv.png, the MenuItem occupies the entire area that is supposed to be empty.

Any help on that?

Comment: have you tried: <MenuItem Header="Finder" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

Comment: it worked perfectly, I'd never imagined that the default alignment would be messed up. post this as an answer so I can mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the stretching menu to be left aligned it should stay where you put it.

Try:

```
<MenuItem Header="Finder" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```