# Horizontal right alignment is not working correctly in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, offset, menuitem, horizontal-alignment

For reference, I am including [Horizontal alignment question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023638/how-do-i-right-align-the-help-menu-item-in-wpf) which is even referenced in the comments of our legacy codebase.

The code is in a .xaml file, the relevant part is:

```
<MenuItem Header="Help" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <MenuItem Header="About"></MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

This code builds. However, when debugging the code, what I see is

[image: :]

I would like to correct this, so that one can see the entire word "Help".

Is there an offset-mechanism in the WPF XAML file or some other way to do this?

NOTE: I have found my own 'hack' that seems to fix the problem, simply adding spaces after Help within the quote-marks works and makes it display better, but surely there must be a more elegant way:

```
<MenuItem Header ="Help       " HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <MenuItem Header="About" CommandParameter="Help_About"></MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

Per request, this is the **entire** context of the menu, some of the items have been obfuscated since they may be proprietary:

```
<Menu xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="appFrameworkMainMenu" 
    Grid.Row="0">


    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>

    <MenuItem Name="Name1" Header="File">

        <MenuItem  Header="MenuItem1a" ></MenuItem>
        <Separator />

        <MenuItem  Header="Exit Application"  ></MenuItem>

    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem Name="Name2" Header="File">

        <MenuItem  Header="MenuItem2a" ></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem  Header="MenuItem2b" ></MenuItem> 
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem Name="Name3" Header="File">

        <MenuItem  Header="MenuItem3a" ></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem  Header="MenuItem3b" ></MenuItem> 
    </MenuItem>

   <!-- align right:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023638/how-do-i-right-align-the-help-menu-item-in-wpf  -->

    <MenuItem Header ="Help       "  HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
        <MenuItem  Header="About"    ></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>

</Menu>
```

Then, per comment suggestion, I tried a simple text block and it appears to be on the left, whether or not the HorizontalAligment = "Right" directive is in the code:

```
<TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Right" >Help me </TextBlock>
```

[image: Result of textblock code]

Comment: Please share your entire `<Menu>` block and try to format your code properly when doing so.

Comment: Instead of the `Menu`, try to put a simple Text with horizontal alignment to the right in `Grid.Row="0"` and see what happens. It looks like your `Grid` is larger than anticipated.

Comment: And your `Menu` should not have things like `xmlns`. It must not be the root element by all means.

Comment: @Martin Braun -- If I remove one of the xmlns tags, it doesn't improve anything.  If I remove them both, there is an error:  Error XDG0004 The default namespace is not defined.   If you have an elegant way around this, please post as answer with example (e.g. namespace above, menu below that, or whatever your work-around would be.)

Comment: Sorry, been a while since I did WPF. `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right"` for the `TextBlock` should reveal if there is a problem on the Grid. Also is `Menu` your root element? You should not do that! You should actually put your `Menu` control in a `DockPanel`, like shown in this article: https://wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/menu-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `Menu` inside `DockPanel` instead:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Common_interface_controls.MenuSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MenuSample" Height="600" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="appFrameworkMainMenu">
            <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemsPanel>
            <MenuItem Name="Name1" Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem1a" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Exit Application" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Name="Name2" Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2a" />
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2b" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Name="Name3" Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem3a" />
                <MenuItem Header="MenuItem3b" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header ="Help" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <MenuItem Header="About" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Grid ....>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code, but I'm pretty sure it should help you to solve this issue.

Comment: This seems worthy, but it just creates a run time error in my system.  One problem is that the class is not instantiated, at least in my codebase, so it is wrong.  I tried variants without it and with a DockPanel but without the Window, and none of it worked for me.

Comment: Due to issues in my comment above, for me the work around with extra spaces after "Help" is tolerable, as to the end users it looks fine, so unless more answers are given I will leave it here.  I upvoted the answer for the effort and because it might help someone else in a similar situation.